# Input string was not in a correct format exception for Math.Round() in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting exception like **Input string was not in a correct format** for below equation for some big values say for example `3225036`

```
decimal eutra = 3225036;

decimal result = 
  Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round((eutra / 256), 0).ToString() + 
  Math.Ceiling((((eutra / 256) - Math.Round((eutra / 256), 0)) * 256)));
```

Actually i was trying to convert an excel equation in to c# which is

`CONCATENATE(ROUND(eutra /256,0),ROUNDUP(((eutra /256)-ROUND(eutra /256,0))*256,0))`

Comment: What's that `.ToString()` doing there if you're calculating with decimals?

Comment: I don't think it's the `Math.Round` that's throwing that exception...

Comment: `Math.Round` doesn't takes strings as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The immediate problem is that `Math.Ceiling((((eutra / 256) - Math.Round((eutra / 256), 0)) * 256))` returns "-52" when `eutra = 3225036`.  Since you're turning the other result into a string first, these are combined as a string to become "12598-52", which isn't a parseable decimal.

It's possible that you want to call `Math.Floor` instead of `Math.Round` on the third division of `eutra`, this should avoid the possibility of a negative number but I'm not sure what you actually want the end result to be.

Comment: Actually i was trying to convert an excel equation in to c# which is = CONCATENATE(ROUND(eutra /256,0),ROUNDUP(((eutra /256)-ROUND(eutra /256,0))*256,0))

Comment: @peter The result for that is a text cell, not a number, so the translation would be `string result = Math.Round((eutra / 256), 0).ToString() + 
  Math.Ceiling((((eutra / 256) - Math.Round((eutra / 256), 0)) * 256));`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on line 4 in your code you are using '.ToString()' on a decimal value which converts the decimal value to a string and then trying to add the string to a second value which is a decimal value this, in turn, gives you a string which is then passed to 'Math.Round()' which requires a decimal value but instead now you're giving it a string value.

See the corrected code below:

```
decimal eutra = 3225036;

decimal result = 
  Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round((eutra / 256), 0) + 
  Math.Ceiling((((eutra / 256) - Math.Round((eutra / 256), 0)) * 256)));
```